# Pages History Issue

Tags: php, silverstripe

I upgraded to Silver-stripe 3.0.5 everything looks great except one thing that related to pages history.

And this is a scenario : 
When I create page and fill all fields ( in content and element tabs ) and press "save and publish", all data saved correctly.

But when press "delete draft" then press "restore" and go to history, I find all versions has the same data on the "element tab"!!

Thanks

Comment: As a note, the latest version of Silverstripe at this point in time is version 3.1.1. This issue might be fixed in the newer version. Try upgrading and see.

Comment: as 3dgoo said, try the latest release. if the error consists, please report this bug on github issue tracker. either way, stackoverflow is for support questions, bug reports will not be processed here.

Comment: This bug fixed in the newer version(3.1)
Thanks guys

Comment: glad to see you got it working. could you please post that as answer and accept it so this question is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this bug fixed in the newer version(3.1)